# Is there a way to remove the hyperlink to a product from "Add to Cart" button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

Trying to create product "pages" for packages instead of the "product" that is created by default.
Is there a way for me to remove the hyperlink from the product when clicking "Add to Cart".
When the user clicks the button, they are currently redirected to the product page which is inside the package.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WC woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url filter hook which you can replace the URL of add to cart button. check the code below.

```
function remove_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url( $url, $WC_Product ){
    $url = '';
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'remove_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 10, 2 );
```